# MPMoviePlayerController Getting Thumbnail from Streaming Video?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to get a Video Thumbnail from Streaming Video when touched to a Button. I've used both;

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
- (void)requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:(NSArray *)playbackTimes timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

But everytime, returned image is null, or getting error below;

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x7ac5560 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media., NSUnderlyingError=0x7a82ea0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12435.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

is there any luck to get thumbnail from streaming video?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download the whole video before you can get a thumb with API requests...as it says the API does not support getting thumbs from remote media